# Pullback on 1-forms

Tags: differential-forms

For my analysis class, I am going through a differential forms book, and have encountered a problem that has made me super confused. I have attached an image of how the book we are using defines the pullback of differential 1-forms $f^*\mu$.[image]

After this section, there is an exercise: Let $U, V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f: U \to V$ is a $C^k$ map. Show that for $\phi \in C^{\infty}(V)$ the chain rule for $f$ and $\phi$: $f^*d\phi = df^*\phi$.

This makes no sense to me. Doesn't $f$ need to be $C^{\infty}$ by definition? And if the notation is map then form (as far as order), then why is it $df^*\phi$, which is reversed? Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The regularity of $f$ may be lower, but then you have to keep track of it. For example, if $\mu$ is $C^k$ and $f$ is $C^\ell$, then $f^*\mu$ can be only guaranteed to be $C^{\min\{k,\ell\}}$. In any case, the point of the problem is to verify that the operations $f^*$ and ${\rm d}$ commute. The expression ${\rm d}f^*\phi$ should be understood as ${\rm d}(f^*\phi)$ or, in other words, ${\rm d}(\phi\circ f)$ (any one more step solves the problem).